# checkbox color in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, browser-extension

I'm working on porting my Chrome extension to Edge for wider availability - everything seems to run fine, except for the styling of the checkboxes. In Chrome, the default styling is a blue color, which works well for the look of the extension, but now the checkbox is grey in Edge. I've tried a few different ways to set the color (in JS styling, HTML, CSS) and nothing seems to work - anyone have experience with styling the color of a checkbox in Edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the color of the checkbox alone may not work. I recommend you to try to design a custom checkbox.

This is a simple example:

```css
 /* The container */
        .container {
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 35px;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 17px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

            /* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
            .container input {
                position: absolute;
                opacity: 0;
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 0;
                width: 0;
            }

        /* Create a custom checkbox */
        .checkmark {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        /* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
        .container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }

        /* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
        .container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
            background-color: #2196F3;
        }

        /* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked)  */
        .checkmark:after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            display: none;
        }

        /* Show the checkmark when checked */
        .container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Style the checkmark/indicator */
        .container .checkmark:after {
            left: 4px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 5px;
            height: 10px;
            border: solid white;
            border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
```

```html
<h1>Custom Checkboxes</h1>
    <label class="container">
        check value
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
```

You can also modify its size or position according to your own requirements. For more details, you could also refer to [How TO - Custom Checkbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp).

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Does anyone have answer for this without this workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with version 93, Edge supports the [accent-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color) CSS property.

> The accent-color CSS property sets the accent color for user-interface controls generated by some elements.
> Browsers that support accent-color currently apply it to the following HTML elements:
>
> - `<input type="checkbox">`
> - `<input type="radio">`
> - `<input type="range">`
> - `<progress>`

It can be used as follows:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    accent-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<input id="clickme" type="checkbox" checked><label for="clickme">Click Me</label>
```